# Python Populating ManyToManyField automativally using same model instance

Tags: django, django-models

I am screwed up to solve a problem for the last 7 days, yet I couldn't solve this problem! so much frustrated now!!!

I want when I create new `GroupMess` with an `admin`, the same admin should automatically add to `members` field,

this is my models:

```
class GroupMess(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='mess_admin'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='mess_members', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.members.add(self.admin)
        super(GroupMess, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

If I try to create new `GroupMess`, it throws me this error:

```
"<GroupMess: GroupMess object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

If i override `save` method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupMess, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
        self.members.add(self.admin)
```

then it doesn't throw any error but the problem is, the `members` field remains blank

Can anyone help to fix this?

I want when I create `GroupMess`, I will add the admin during creating groupmess and the `members` filed should be filled automatically with the `admin`

***I mean, A group admin also will be a group member ***

Comment: The first issue is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships), and is rather obvious: if one of the instances in the many2many doesn't have a primary key set, it cannot be referenced by a foreign key.

Comment: So how can i solve this problem? I want a admin of group also will be a members

Comment: MCVE are not only for posting on forums or bugtrackers - they are an invaluable debugging tool. Actually I (almost) never ask for help here or on forums because when I have an issue that don't get quickly solved using basic debugging techniques (unittests, logging, tracing thru a step debugger), the very next  thing I do is to try and write a proper MCVE - which usually makes the root cause quite obvious. Please believe that I can feel your pain, but seven days on such an issue and not having a MCVE yet seems quite alien to me. Did you _at _least_ trace the execution under the step debugger ?

Comment: How do you verify that "members field remains blank"?

Comment: No need to verify this

Comment: How can i post minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

After you add the members to the Group model, save it again.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.members.add(self.admin)
        self.save()
```